# What's the powershell equivalent to "%~dpn0" in batch?

Tags: hard-drive, batch, powershell

I'm new to powershell and I asked myself how could I put the following variables in a powershell script? I know how to set a variable in powershell, but I don't know how to get `"%~dpn0"`.

```
set pgm=%~n0
set log=%~dpn0.log
set csv=%~dpn0.csv
set dir=%~dp0users
set txt=%~n0.txt
set fix=%~dpn0.fix
```

Comment: What an answerer was helpful enough to state  "In batch, %~dpn0 returns the Drive, Path and Name of the currently executing script."  You were not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In batch, `%~dpn0` returns the Drive, Path and Name of the currently executing script.

To do the same in a PowerShell script you can use `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition`.

eg:

```
$scriptPathAndName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
write-host $scriptPathAndName
```

To get just the path to the script you could use:

```
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
write-host $scriptPath
```

(Note: in Powershell v3+ you can get the script's path (without the name) by referencing the predefined variable `$PSScriptRoot`)

To get just the name of the script:

```
$scriptName = split-path -leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
write-host $scriptName
```

More info on Split-Path's options: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849809.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

Then I think `-Parent` will give you the PWD, but you may not need that.